# ubuntu - медленное wifi соединение при подключении HDMI

Tags: linux, hdmi, wireless

Каждый раз при подключении HDMI или внешнего винта сильно увеличивается пинг на беспроводных соединениях. У меня DELL Vostro 5470, Ubuntu 16.04 (но в принципе и на debian 9), Intel Wireless-N 7260.
По проводу все нормально.

Comment: Возможно, питание?

Comment: А может просто наводка.  Хорошо бы проверить скорость соединения с другого устройства в этот же момент.

Comment: Интернет тут не причем 100%. Как только я вынимаю кабель - все нормализуется. А что с питанием может быть? В смысле от блока питания меньшее напряжение? Энергосбережение отключено, подключаю с зарядкой, пробовал 2 кабеля hdmi, но за их качество я не уверен

Comment: если блок питания обеспечивает "в притык", то дополнительная нагрузка либо вызывает срабатывание защиты ( с последующим выключением), либо просто падает напряжение. А некоторые "блоки" (например, вайфай модуль) могут работать нестабильно при понижении питания. А некоторые просто имеют свой стабилизатор.

Comment: Ну в ноуте же батарея стоит. Плохо, что не попробовал на Винде, как купил бук, сразу поставил Линукс. А со стороны ос какие то проблемы могут быть?